# Efficient Way of subset a dataframe into small ones based on unique values and simultaneously write out to csv file

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, csv

What is the most efficient way to subset a large dataframe `df` into small subsets based on a unique/ filter condition? For example, I have a dataset with a dimension of 22050 rows with 5 columns, something like this

```
id, nationality, age, gender, income 
10001, France, 20, M, 45007
13328, UK, 52, F, 72308
11654, USA, 57, F, 95645
11765, UK, 39, M, 77343
10081, UAE, 41,M, 83117
10503, France, 22, F, 25665
```

There are 15 unique nationalities in the entire dataset, I want to subset the dataset into 15 dataframes based on the 15 unique countries and simultaneously write out the 15 dataframes in 15 `csv` output files.

Desired output should look like this

dataframe-one in a `csv` file

```
id, nationality, age, gender, income
10001, France, 20, M, 45007
10503, France, 22, F, 25665
```

dataframe-two in a `csv` file

```
13328, UK, 52, F, 72308
11765, UK, 39, M, 77343
```

likewise for dataframes 3 to 15

Here is my attempt:

```
fran = df[df.nationality == 'France']
fran.to_csv(file_name, sep=',')
uk = df[df.nationality =='UK']
uk.to_csv(file_name, sep=',')
USA = df[df.nationality == 'USA']
usa.to_csv(file_name, sep=',')
```

I want a more efficient way, `apply | lambda` or a `loop` approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to use `pandas` you can loop over a grouped dataframe

```
for i, part_df in df.groupby('nationality'):
    part_df.to_csv(f'{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Your example is not clear if you want comma or tab delimiter. For a tab delimited file add `sep='\t'` as an argument to `to_csv`.

Comment: mikksu, thanks a lot- works fine. I have edited `sep  = ' \t ' `  to `sep = ',' `.

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can split the data by the 'nationality' column into a `list` of `data.frame`

```
lst1 <- split(df, df$nationality)
```

Then loop over the `list` and write it to different files

```
lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.csv(lst[[nm]], 
          paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

NOTE: The `split` method would be much faster than the `==` based subsetting

Comment: @RickyTricky is this a python or R question.  Your code suggested `R` solution